# What does "other" mean in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

So i just started learning object oriented programming in ***python 3*** and i came across the "`__add__`" method and i don't understand what " ***other*** " is and what it does. I tried to look on the internet for an answer but i found nothing, here is an example of my code:

```
import math

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __add__(self, other):
        f = self.x + other.x
        e = self.y + other.y
```

Comment: If you create an instance from `MyClass` for example with name  `m` and if you wanna add another number to `m`, `other` will hold that number or object in  `m + another_obj`.

Comment: feel free to accept an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> what " other " is and what it does.

It is the name of a parameter. The parameter `other` is (for example) another instance of `MyClass`. Take the following example:

```
a = MyClass(1, 2)
b = MyClass(3, 4)
# the next line calls MyClass.__add__ on the instance a
c = a + b
```

In this case `a` is `self` and `b` is `other`.

The code for `__add__` in your example is incomplete, it should really return a new `MyClass` instance.

```
def __add__(self, other):
    f = self.x + other.x
    e = self.y + other.y
    return MyClass(f, e)
```

Answer (score 1):

`other` is nothing but an argument name. You can call it whatever you want, although methods obey some conventions to make the code clearer.

Here are some argument names that usually have a special meaning.

- `self`: an argument expected to be the instance from which the method
  was called
- `other`: an argument expected to be an instance of the class, but not
  the one calling the method
- `cls`: the class itself

In particular, the method `__add__` is called by the `+` operator.

```
self + other
```

... is what calls...

```
self.__add__(other)
```

### Example

```
class MyNumber(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        print('I am', self)
        print('I encountered', other)
        return super().__add__(other)

x = MyNumber(2)
y = MyNumber(3)

x + y
```

### Output

```
I am 2
I encountered 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`other` in this case is called a "parameter". A parameter is kind-of like a "hole" in a function definition that you can later fill with a concrete value called an "argument".

For example, in

```
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b
```

`a` and `b` are parameters to the function `foo`, and when you call

```
foo(3, 5)
```

then `3` and `5` are arguments which are bound to the parameters, such that for this particular invocation of the function, the code that is executed is

```
3 + 5
```

Answer (score 0):

other is the parameter of this very method, you can use it with just this method, you can replace "other" with anything else.
self is an explicit word that you can not change, it is used to refer to attributes of this object of this class and you can use it with as many def as you want

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).